# Spark error when running TPCDS benchmark datasets - Could not find dsdgen

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Im trying to build the TPCDS benchmark datasets, by following this website.

https://xuechendi.github.io/2019/07/12/Prepare-TPCDS-For-Spark

when I run this:

```
scala> [troberts@master1 spark-sql-perf]$ spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode cliers /home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/target/scala-2.11/spark-sql-perf_2.11-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -i TPCDPreparation.scala
```

I get this error? Im wondering if its something to do with permissions as the file dsdgen definitely exists at that location on each of the worker nodes /home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Aborting TaskSet 0.0 because task 0 (partition 0)
>   cannot run anywhere due to node and executor blacklist.
>   Most recent failure:
>   Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, worker1.mycluster.com, executor 1): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find dsdgen at /home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen or //home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen. Run install
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)

Any ideas appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Ok so I got it running, by putting the dsdgen into the /tmp folder on each of the worker nodes. So it must have been a permissions issue, however I did actually try running chmod 777 /home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen - but this didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Could not find dsdgen at /home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen or //home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen
```

You need to have TPCDS installed first.

[spark-sql-perf docs](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sql-perf/blob/e1e1365a8795b76a796dab3a51259be9343c80de/README.md#setup-a-benchmark) from tool you've used:

```
Before running any query, a dataset needs to be setup by creating a Benchmark object. 
Generating the TPCDS data requires dsdgen built and available on the machines. 
We have a fork of dsdgen that you will need. 

The fork includes changes to generate TPCDS data to stdout, so that this library can pipe them directly to Spark, without intermediate files. 
Therefore, this library will not work with the vanilla TPCDS kit.

TPCDS kit needs to be installed on all cluster executor nodes under the same path!
```

Please, configure TPCDC toolkit from [databricks](https://github.com/databricks/tpcds-kit)

Comment: Hey, I ran this command on each of the data nodes:                                                          > git clone https://github.com/databricks/tpcds-kit.git
cd tpcds-kit/tools
make OS=LINUX                                                                                                                     And this was before I had the issue. Does that mean building TPCDS, if so then I had already installed tpcds first.

Comment: are you sure it's accessible from the same user spark runs on the nodes under `/home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen` path (and `dsdgen` is executable)?

Comment: No not really sure - as I said in the comment, doing a chmod 777 /home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen didn't seem to do anything, but putting it in tmp did - I assume that its accessible in the tmp one, but not in /home/troberts/spark-sql-perf/tpcds-kit/tools/dsdgen, even with the chmod 777

Comment: not sure it's a good idea to put `tpcds-kit` under user home. All parent paths also should be accessible then. In your case, you should run `chmod -R 777 $HOME` to make it works